# How do I parse HTML to XML and save to database?

Tags: iphone, xml-database

I would like to parse some HTML website information and store it as XML as my database. As I see there is a parse function called hpple and it just parse it information without store in database and the efficiency isn't that what I expected.

Comment: Can you explain to us, what you have tried so far? Some code could be useful providing an answer.

Comment: What XML database? Many XML databases have the ability to import HTML directly, cleaning it up in the process.